# Set minimum height for each component in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

Is there any method I could implement that will ensure each button within the pane maintains a minimum height? I have attempted using `itembutton.setSize()` method but it has no effect.

```
JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel();

itemPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

for(final Item i: list){
    JButton itemButton = new JButton(i.getName());
    itemPanel.add(itemButton);
}

JScrollPane itemPane = new JScrollPane(itemPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

`itembutton.setMinimumSize(minimumSize)` ?

**Edit:** Just found that,  as [this java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) seems to tell, there is no way to do that with GridLayout.

> Each component takes all the available space within its cell, and each cell is exactly the same size

So I guess you'll have to try another layout. I can suggest (don't know if it's well suited but it works) `GridBagLayout`. Example with 2 buttons:

```
itemPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.weightx = 0.5;
itemPanel.add(new JButton("A"), c);
c.gridx = 1;
c.weightx = 0.5;
itemPanel.add(new JButton("B"), c);
```

Have a look to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: Note that I believe (not sure about that) it also depends on the choosen layout and his hints about sizes.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem originates from one of my chosen layouts. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: So setMinimumSize() has no effect ?

Comment: Unfortunately, setMinimumSize() had no effect.

Comment: @rmp2150 don't even think of using any of the setXXSize methods, ever http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519 - instead use a LayoutManager that supports your requirement